# Module Federation Loading Nested App route

Tags: javascript, angular, micro-frontend, webpack-module-federation, angular-module-federation

I have a app in the below structure

---Main App (router-outlet>)
--Animal ()
-Dashboard.  (url app/dog/dashboard)

--Animal (router-outlet>)
-Dashboard (url app/cat/dashboard)

Now I want to separate the Dashboard component, i.e DogDashboard and CatDashboard and load it via the router-outlet of Animal component through module federation.

What I could do so far is create the Main App as shell, create another app for Dogdasboard, but when I navigate to cat dashboard via remotes, the parent router-outlet is used and not the child (animal router outlet). Any idea if this can be done?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the matcher with the "startsWith" of @angular-architects/module-federation-tools

Take a look: https://www.angulararchitects.io/en/aktuelles/multi-framework-and-version-micro-frontends-with-module-federation-your-4-steps-guide/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).